# Why doesn't ng-class work with a class name?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-ng-class

I wrote the following code:

```
 <style>
    .dotted {
         border:dotted;
     }
 </style>

....

 <p ng-style = "mystyle"  ng-class="dotted "> {{ answer }} </p>
```

My purpose was that the

element will be put inside dotted border line. It doesn't work. I looked at Angular documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and I saw that:

> If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or
>   more space-delimited class names.

I understand that ng-class may contain a class name I defined inside -tag. So.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just use class in this example. HTML 'class' isn't deprecated, angular adds to it, which is the concept of web components. See my answer for usage.

Answer (score 5):

`ng-class` directive evaluates its value against `scope` of DOM which is bound to, so here `dotted` get evaluated with scope and it doesn't have value. So you have to provide it as `'dotted'`(string)

```
ng-class="'dotted'"
```

In your case you should directly use `class="dotted"` as your class seems to be static.

Comment: thanks. How can you understand it from Angular documentation?

Comment: @CrazySynthax documentation clearly said that `ng-class="expression"` where expression can be `scope` bindings

Comment: but 'dotted' is not scope binding

Comment: @CrazySynthax that's why I had `'dotted'`(wrapped with single qoute inside `ng-class`), which will evaluated as `dotted` & `ng-class` put that evaluated value inside `class` attribute

Answer (score 0):

ng-class takes an evaluation so it expects something like this:

```
ng-class="{class: booleanVar}"
```

if your class has a hyphen use it with quotes like this:

```
ng-class="{'my-class-name': someVar === someThing}"
```

Or a function as such:

```
ng-class="{'my-class-name': someFuncReturningTruthyValue()}"
```